# Как собрать OpenSSL из исходников для WIndows/VS2019

Tags: c++, openssl

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто нибудь собирал OpenSSL для VS2019 для Windows ?

У меня возникает проблема при сборке - для x86, хотя для x64 static и dll - debug/release собрались без проблем по описанию на гитхабе.

Для примера я запускаю командную строку VS2019, ввожу следующие команды для сборки статик x64 для debug:

> cd C:\path\openssl
>
> perl Configure VC-WIN64A --debug --prefix="path_to_folder_debug"
> --openssldir="path_to_temp_folder_openSSL" no-shared
>
> nmake
>
> nmake install_sw

Все работает отлично, .lib файл и хедеры появляются в указанной папке.

Но, как только я делаю тоже самое для x86, меняю только, как указано на другую команду:

> perl Configure VC-WIN32 --debug --prefix="path_to_folder_debug"
> --openssldir="path_to_temp_folder_openSSL" no-shared

Происходит ошибка:

> fatal error LNK1112: тип компьютера модуля "x64" конфликтует с типом
> целевого компьютера "x86"
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86
> x86\lib.EXE" : возвращенный код "0x458" Stop. NMAKE : fatal error

> U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86
> x86\nmake.exe" : возвращенный код "0x2" Stop.

Но из за чего происходит конфликт ?

PS: пробывал и в x86 VS2019 и в x64 VS2019.

Comment: ¿Это полный лог сборки?

Comment: Если вы это делаете в той же папке, в какой собирали вариант x64 - хорошо бы вычистить ранее сгенеренные объектники

Comment: @user7860670, нет, боюсь, что полный лог сюда не поместится.

Comment: @gbg, вообщем получилось вот так: для x64 я указывал исходники скаченные с гитхаба, для x86 выкидывалась ошибка, попробовал заменить папку с с исходниками скаченными с официального сайта https://www.openssl.org/source/ - после этого собралось без ошибок. Или между исходниками на гитхабе и .openssl.org - реально есть ккая то разница или я когда менял папку сделал, что то еще, что убрало ошибку.